# Refactoring to one line statement bool value

Tags: c#

Is there a way to turn this into a one-liner it works as does what its meant to do but I can't help but think it could be one line as I am just simply returning a bool.

```
private bool RequiresTable() {
  return Settings.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.NameSpace == "XXX");
}
```

Comment: `private bool RequiresTable() => Settings.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.NameSpace == "XXX");`?

Comment: In addition to @GSerg's comment above, the *simplest* way would be to just remove newlines: `private bool RequiresTable() { return Settings.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.NameSpace == "XXX"); }`

Comment: Where is the second line of `Settings.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.NameSpace == "XXX")`? What is the question?

Comment: It is one line... Why is there an excessive need to remove LoC where it is not needed

Comment: What is *one-liner* in your understanding? Can you show an example?

Comment: This did not require to be closed was a valid understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C#6, you can write

```
private bool RequiresTable() => Settings.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.NameSpace == "XXX");
```

Your question use a syntax called statement body and mine use one called expression body. The change is purely syntactic.

You can learn more about it on the official documentation: [Expression-bodied members (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Answer (score 1):

I mean, this is technically a one liner, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

```cs
private bool RequiresTable() => Setting.Filter.Criteria.Any(w => w.Namespace == "XXX");
```